# Get the bitmap from decoded output buffers of android mediacodec without using any surface output

Tags: android-bitmap, android-mediacodec, bytebuffer

An android mediacodec is configured to have bytebuffer output not configured as surface output.

Then How can I save the bitmap from the decoded frame output (outputBuffer) obtained from getoutputBuffer(output_buf_index)?

I have tried bmp.copyPixelsFromBuffer(outputBuffer) after calling outputBuffer.rewind()

But I am getting an error of **"java.lang.RuntimeException: Buffer not large enough for pixels"** from copyPixelsFromBuffer() API.

***Can anyone please tell me how can I get the bitmap from the decoded output buffer if mediacodec is not configured as surface?***